# Are there any good reasons to use bit shifting except for quick math?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I understand bitwise operations and how they might be useful for different purposes, e.g. permissions. However, I don't seem to understand what use the bit shift operators are. I understand how they work, but I can't think of any scenarios where I might want to use them unless I want to do some really quick multiplication or division. Are there any other reasons to use bit-shifting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have you ever had to use bit shifting in real projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520625/have-you-ever-had-to-use-bit-shifting-in-real-projects)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many reasons, here are some:

1. Let's say you represent a black and white image as a sequence of bits and you want to set a single pixel in this image generically.  For example your byte offset may be x>>3 and your bit offset may be x & 0x7 and you can set that bit by: byte = byte | (1 << (x & 0x7));
2. Implementing data compression algorithms where you deal with variable length bit sequences, e.g. huffman coding.
3. You're are interacting with some hardware, e.g. a serial communication device, and you need to read or set some control bits.

For those and other reasons most processors have bit shift and/or rotation instructions as well as other logic instructions (and/or/xor/not).

Historically multiplication and division were significantly slower as they are more complex operations and some CPUs didn't have those at all.

Also see here:
[Have you ever had to use bit shifting in real projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520625/have-you-ever-had-to-use-bit-shifting-in-real-projects)

Answer (score 7):

As you indicate, a left shift is the same thing as a multiplication by two.  At least it is when we're talking about unsigned quantities.  The meaning of a "left shift" of a signed quantity is ... language dependent.

With modern compilers, there's really no difference between writing "i = x*2;"  and "i = x << 1;"  The compiler will generate the most efficient code.  So in that sense there's no reason to prefer shift over multiply.

Some algorithms work by shifting a quantity left by one bit and then setting the low bit to either 0 or 1.  Some simple compression algorithms work this way.  For example, if your accumulated value is in the variable x, and the current value (0 or 1) is in y, then it makes more sense to write "x = (x << 1) | y", rather than "x = (x * 2) + y".  Both do the same thing, but the first is more *notationally* correct.  You don't have to think, "oh, right, multiply by two is the same as a left shift."

Also, when you're talking about algorithms that shift bits, it's more convenient to shift left or right by a particular number of bits than to figure out what multiple of 2 you want to multiply or divide by.

So, whereas there's typically no performance benefit to shifting rather than multiplying--at least not when working with high level languages--there are times when having the ability to shift makes what you're doing more easily understood.

Answer (score 6):

There are lot of places where bit shift operations are regularly used outside of their usage in numerical computations. For example, [Bitboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) is a data structure that is commonly used in board games for board representation. Some of the strongest chess engines use this data structure mainly for speed and ease of move generation and evaluation. These programs use bit operations heavily and bit-shift operations specifically are used in a lot of contexts - such as finding bit masks, generating new moves on the board, computing logarithm very quickly, etc. There are even very advanced numerical computations that can be done elegantly by clever use of bit operations. Check out [this site](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for bit twiddling hacks - a lot of those algorithms use shift operators. Bit shift operations are regularly used in device driver programming, codec development, embedded systems programming and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Shifting allows accessing specific bits within a variable.  The expression `(n >> p) & ((1 << m) - 1)` retrieves an `m`-bit portion of the variable `n` with an offset of `p` bits from the right.

This allows your program to use integers that aren't multiples of 8 bits, which is useful for data compression.

For example, I used it in my [Netflix Prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/) programs to pack records (22-bit user ID + 15-bit movie ID + 12-bit date + 3-bit rating) into a `uint64_t` (with 12 bits to spare).

A very common special case is to pack 8 `bool` variables into each byte.  (Unix file permissions, black-and-white bitmaps, [CPU flags registers](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/flags-and-bit-level-instructions#toc2), etc.)

Also, bit manipulation is used in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which is a very popular character encoding.  Unicode characters are represented by distributing their bits across 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes.